# GWT Developer Plugin complains when doing a debug with Chrome

Tags: java, gwt, google-chrome

Following is the error that occurd while I rendered a  code  earlier rendered in firefox  into chrome.

An unexpected error has occured:Something othen than a short was returned from JSNI method
'@com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node::getNodeType()':JS value of type undefined,expected short.Hit OK to restart your session.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5778) with Chrome. This is not yet fixed as per the comments in the issue. So, the solution is to use some other browser for development mode.

Comment: See specifically [comment #65](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5778#c65). Also, I believe it won't be fixed, as the SuperDevMode is coming.